# File type from buffer using file-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried finding type of file using file-type module but when i try to run it gives me error that "error:.... fileType.fromBuffer is not a function.

`

```
const fileType = require('file-type');
const readChunk = require('read-chunk');
exports.ext = async function(file) {
const buffer = readChunk.sync(file, 0, 512)
let type = await fileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
console.log("type of file",type)
return value
```

`

this is in utils.js file and i am calling it in other type.js file

`

```
var extension =  await utils.ext('ABC.png')
 console.log(extension)
```

`

Can anybody tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like there is a miss in npm documentation for the module [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).
The error which you are getting means the module doesn't expose such a method(fromBuffer).

Note that the function `fromBuffer` is now `fileTypeFromBuffer` in the latest version of the package.

the fileType accepts buffer as an input i.e.

```
await fileType.fileTypeFromBuffer(buffer)
```

kindly follow this [file](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/blob/master/index.d.ts) from the module source

Comment: This gives me: `This expression is not callable` and `Type 'typeof import(path) has no call signatures`. I'm importing it like this `import * as fileType from 'file-type'`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: That happened because my `file-type` was @17.1.1. Installed @16.5.1 and works now

Comment: Use `fileTypeFromBuffer`